# with conditional ?: expression, at what point do postfix operations occur?

Tags: c

For example, the difference between these two statements:

```
if ( ucNum++ >= 3 ) // ucNum incremented after comparing its value to 3, correct?
{
    ucNum = 0;
}
```

vs.

```
ucNum++ >= 3 ? ucNum = 0 : 1; // does incrementing it happen somewhere in the middle of the inline?
```

Perhaps it is compiler specific. Where *should* it occur in the conditional expression?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - it is according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules are that the condition is evaluated before choosing which alternative to evaluate. Since part of the evaluation is the `++`, the increment will occur before the assignment (if the assignment occurs at all).

As @caf comments, there is a sequence point after the controlling expression. So, while (as David Thornley points out) the order of expression evaluations can be rearranged by the compiler (particularly side effect evaluations), the rearranging cannot cross sequence points.

Comment: @Tudor - perhaps not from a logical perspective, but there is no short-circuit evaluation for `++` like there is for logical `||` and `&&`. The expression `ucNum++` must be evaluated for the condition to be evaluated and evaluating the expression includes the post-increment.

Comment: Evaluation order doesn't apply to side effects in C.  If it did, `a = n[a++]` would be well defined, and it isn't.

Comment: @DavidThornley - Good point! Now I think my answer is wrong. I'd delete it, except SO won't let me delete an accepted answer. :(

Comment: Your original answer was correct.  A conditional expression has a sequence point after the controlling expression (the `ucNum++ >= 3` in this case) and before the second or third expression is evaluated - in this case, the `++` must be applied before the `ucNum = 0`.  See §6.5.15 in the C99 standard.

Comment: @caf - Thanks. I missed that. I'll put back the answer and point out your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've tested this practically (good thing printf returns int) with:

```
int ucNum = 4;
ucNum++ >= 3 ? printf("%d", ucNum) : 1;
```

Since the condition is true, it goes to the printf which prints 5. So definitely ucNum is incremented between the evaluation of the condition and the choosing of the return value.

Comment: Testing doesn't work here.  It tells you what happens with one particular program on one particular version of one particular compiler.  Since C has plenty of undefined, unspecified, and implementation-dependent behavior, relying on single tests will get you in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for 6.5.15/4 in the C Standard.  The first expression is completely evaluated, including side effects, before the selected one of the other two.  This is not compiler-dependent, except in the sense that some compilers may be broken.